# SimpleDateFormat API displays wrong Date

Tags: java, simpledateformat

Tried formatting few dates using SimpleDateFormat API

```
String[] dates={"18-01-2015","9-02-2015","21-03-2015"};
for(String s:dates){
    SimpleDateFormat format=new SimpleDateFormat("DD-MM-yyyy");
    Date date=format.parse(s);
    System.out.println(date);
}
```

Output:

```
Sun Jan 18 00:00:00 IST 2015
Fri Jan 09 00:00:00 IST 2015
Wed Jan 21 00:00:00 IST 2015
```

You could notice for all dates it displays JAN instead of FEB/MAR.

Comment: it should be `dd-MM-yyyy`

Comment: @Raj I can not believe it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want `dd` instead of `DD` when you construct the `SimpleDateFormat`. `DD` means "day of year", not "day of month". *Every* time `SimpleDateFormat` looks like it's doing the wrong thing, you should consult the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and check your pattern text really, really carefully - particularly capitalization.

(There are other things that can go wrong of course - I've got a [blog post](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2015/05/05/common-mistakes-in-datetime-formatting-and-parsing/) for the most common ones.)